# SharePoint Document Workspace Permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Does anyone know the minimum permissions as user must have to create a document workspace?  The problem I have is that I want to users to be able to create document workspaces but to do this I have had to grant the user Create Subsites permission, this however means they can now create other subsites.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want a user to be able to create a document workspace, they will also have to have rights to create subsites.

If you're able to remove the need for the user to create document workspaces, then you probably have more options. But this may not be possible for you.

Answer (score 2):

To get around this I simply wrapped the Site Action menu on the master page in a placeholder. Then in the code behind page tested for a permission that I knew the user wouldn't have. This does stop the user from having any access to the Site Action menu but this is fine for my solution.

```
actionMenuPlaceholder.Visible = (
  SPContext.Current.Web.UserIsWebAdmin ||
  SPContext.Current.Web.UserIsSiteAdmin ||
  SPContext.Current.Web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ManageWeb)
);
```